# what's the best way to render in cycles in 3.0

Tags: rendering

while rendering with tiles, I got the impression this isn't the best method anymore?
Tell me more, please.
Thanks.

Comment: Hello, FYI this site is not a regular forum, we try to keep Questions and Answers as objective as possible, so we cant' really answer questions which begin with "What's the best way" since this is bound to be subjective. You can go to https://blenderartists.org/ instead which is more like a regular forum. Cheers